# Error 522 on www.example.com when using Cloudflare Pages, but non-www version works fine

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I've set up my website with Cloudflare Pages and I'm facing an unusual issue. When I access my website using https://www.example.com, I get an Error 522 (connection timed out). However, when I access the non-www version https://example.com, it works perfectly.

Here are my DNS settings on Cloudflare:

```
CNAME
subdomain
subdomain.pages.dev
Proxied

CNAME
example.com
example.pages.dev
Proxied

CNAME
www
example.pages.dev
Proxied

MX
example.com
routeX.mx.cloudflare.net
DNS only

MX
example.com
routeY.mx.cloudflare.net
DNS only

MX
example.com
routeZ.mx.cloudflare.net
DNS only

TXT
_dmarc
v=DMARC1; p=none;
DNS only

TXT
example.com
v=spf1 include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net include:_spf.mail.fakeprovider.com ~all
DNS only
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue with Cloudflare Pages? Any guidance on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your dns records are correct wait for sometime to reflect the changes.